# Installing SCIP on OSX: outdated libisl?

Tags: scip

I'm trying to install SCIP on OSX mavericks. I've downloaded the tarball [here](http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-3.2.0.tgz), extracted it, and have tried to compile it using

```
make scipoptlib GMP=false ZLIB=false READLINE=false SHARED=true
```

This gives me error 1 below. My interpretation of error 1 is that `/usr/local/lib/libisl.10.dylib` does not exist. That's correct: I have isl.0.14.1, located at `/usr/local/Cellar/isl/0.14.1`. And in fact I can't install isl.0.10.1, because the compiler options it expects don't work with the current version of gcc (I think; see error 2 below).

Can I tell SCIP to use isl.0.14.1, and if so, how?

```
**error 1:**
** Extracting SoPlex archive "/Applications/scipoptsuite-3.2.0/soplex-2.2.0.tgz".
    ** Extracting ZIMPL archive "/Applications/scipoptsuite-3.2.0/zimpl-3.3.3.tgz".
    ** Extracting SCIP archive "/Applications/scipoptsuite-3.2.0/scip-3.2.0.tgz".
    ** compile libraries statically with compiler flag -fPIC
    rm -rf obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.normal.opt/* bin/zimpl-3.3.3.darwin.x86_64.gnu.normal.opt lib/libzimpl-3.3.3.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a lib/libzimpl-3.3.3.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.dbl.a lib/libzimpl.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a bin/zimpl.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt bin/zimpl
    ** Creating directory "/Applications/scipoptsuite-3.2.0/scip-3.2.0/lib".
    ** Creating directory "/Applications/scipoptsuite-3.2.0/scip-3.2.0/lib/zimplinc".

    ** Building SoPlex library "/Applications/scipoptsuite-3.2.0/soplex-2.2.0/lib/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a".
    -> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/changesoplex.o
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libisl.10.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.9.1/cc1plus
      Reason: image not found
    g++: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1plus)
    make[4]: *** [obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/changesoplex.o] Abort trap: 6
    make[3]: [makelibfile] Error 2 (ignored)
    -> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/changesoplex.o
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libisl.10.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.9.1/cc1plus
      Reason: image not found
    g++: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1plus)
    make[4]: *** [obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/changesoplex.o] Abort trap: 6
    make[3]: [all] Error 2 (ignored)

    ** ZIMPL support disabled.

    ** Creating necessary soft-links.

    ** Building SCIP libraries and executable.
    -> generating necessary links

    - Current settings: LPS=spx OSTYPE=darwin ARCH=x86_64 COMP=gnu SUFFIX= ZIMPL=false ZIMPLOPT=opt IPOPT=false IPOPTOPT=opt EXPRINT=cppad GAMS=false

    * SCIP needs some softlinks to external programs, in particular, LP-solvers.
    * Please insert the paths to the corresponding directories/libraries below.
    * The links will be installed in the 'lib' directory.
    * For more information and if you experience problems see the INSTALL file.

      -> "spxinc" is the path to the SoPlex "src" directory, e.g., "../../soplex/src".
      -> "libsoplex.*" is the path to the SoPlex library, e.g., "../../soplex/lib/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a"
    -> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o
    dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libisl.10.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.9.1/cc1
      Reason: image not found
    gcc: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1)
    make[4]: *** [obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o] Abort trap: 6
    make[3]: *** [makesciplibfile] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [scipbinary] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [scipbinary] Error 2
    make: *** [scipoptlib] Error 2
```

**error 2**, produced by running ./configure in libisl.10 directory:
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
    running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

```
It was created by isl configure 0.10, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = dhcp-143-183.caltech.edu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 13.4.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
         Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 16.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 327 tasks, 1905 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 4.32, Mach factor: 0.47
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/madeleine/anaconda/bin/
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/local/go/bin
PATH: /usr/texbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Applications/spark-0.9.1-bin-hadoop2/bin
PATH: /Applications/Julia-0.3.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2762: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2830: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2841: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2891: result: yes
configure:3032: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3071: result: ./install-sh -c -d
configure:3084: checking for gawk
configure:3114: result: no
configure:3084: checking for mawk
configure:3114: result: no
configure:3084: checking for nawk
configure:3114: result: no
configure:3084: checking for awk
configure:3100: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:3111: result: awk
configure:3122: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3144: result: yes
configure:3287: checking for gcc
configure:3303: found /usr/local/bin/gcc
configure:3314: result: gcc
configure:3543: checking for C compiler version
configure:3552: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Homebrew gcc 4.9.1) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3563: $? = 0
configure:3552: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 4.9.1' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (Homebrew gcc 4.9.1)
configure:3563: $? = 0
configure:3552: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3563: $? = 1
configure:3552: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3563: $? = 1
configure:3583: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3605: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libisl.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.9.1/cc1
  Reason: image not found
gcc: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1)
./configure: line 3607:  9063 Abort trap: 6           $CC $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS 1>&5
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice below! You're right: my (homebrew) gcc was broken. I uninstalled it, and the rest of the installation of SCIP proceeded just fine using the Apple version it fell back to: `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the impression that the C++ compiler itself is broken:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libisl.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.9.1/cc1plus
```

Maybe try a simple (hello-world) C++ program first to test that the compiler itself is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where or why the SCIP Optimization Suite would be using `isl`. To be precise, in your case not SCIP fails to compile but SoPlex. Have you checked whether you can compile SoPlex alone? Just go into the subdirectory and type `make` or `make SHARED=true GMP=false ZLIB=false` to match the original command.

Have you compiled some other code with your compiler? It may also be that your `gcc` itself is broken.